# How to read .gif file from internal storage?

Tags: android, stream, storage, inputstream, gif

I want to read .gif file from internal storage. I can read image, mp3 but not .gif. Actually I am searching global way to read any types of file.

Regards

Edit:

```
private void globalGif() throws FileNotFoundException{
    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("frog");
    GifMovieView gmv = new GifMovieView(getApplicationContext(), fis);
    setContentView(gmv);
}
```

I use this code but it shows this error. `divide by zero` fis haven't gif file.

Comment: Could You share some code, logcat output?

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 1):

you can find the path of image following way

```
 File file= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/Images/a.gif");

    But you can not set this gif image to ImageView the gif file is show in webView.
```

Comment: I take my file in internal storage. Is it possible to reach internal storage?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119881/read-images-byte-by-byte-from-android-internal-storage-takes-too-much-time

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read gif files, take a look at the [`Movie class`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Movie.html).

Here's a [nice tutorial](http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/) which show you how to load a gif and show it.

Comment: ZouZou, I know this tutorial. I can't load InputStream with gif file.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `openFileInput("frog.gif");` ? Are you sure that the gif file is in the right folder/place ?

Comment: If I use "frog", it gives me divide zero error. If I use "frog.gif" I get no such file in directories error. But I am confident file is here. I exported to desktop and saw my eyes.

Comment: My files saved "frog" , I changed "frog.gif". But it is still same error.

Comment: Keep it with the name "frog.gif" for your file, now the error you have is more comprehensible. Are you sure that you're getting the file in the right place when you call `openFileInput("frog.gif");` ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Because I can read `mp3` and `.png` files from this method. All files in same folder. (under `com.example.project/files` folder)

Comment: And the you rename the file name as frog.gif in your files folder ? That's very weird.

Comment: Yes, I renamed. openFileInput returns null. My main problem is this.

Comment: read this please : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10262631/1587046 And try to closely follow the tutorial to see what's the error (store the gif file in assets folder and load it from there).

Comment: I used this code and it works properly. 

InputStream stream = getAssets().open("bla.gif");

GifMovieView gmv = new GifMovieView(getApplicationContext(), stream);
setContentView(gmv);

Comment: Ok cool so the error is that the program can't locate the file. So keep of using assets (which I think is the best choice) or try to know why the method can't find the file.